# How to bring two Cloud Run Apps under one domain to avoid CORS

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have two apps I wanted to have "fully managed" by Cloud Run. One is a pure Vue.js SPA and the other is the belonging backend server for it that is connected to a MySQL and also fetches some other API endpoints.

Now I have deployed both apps but am totally unaware on how I can give the frontend app access to the backend app. They should be both running on the same domain to avoid the frontend from.

Current URL of the frontend app: `https://myapp-xl23p3zuiq-ew.a.run.app`

So I'd love to have the server accessible by: `https://myapp-xl23p3zuiq-ew.a.run.app/api`

Is this somewhat possible to achieve with Cloud Run?

Comment: This is a highly requested feature. Stay tuned.

Comment: @Pentium10 - I don't think Cloud Run will be supporting path-based routing. The HTTPS load balancer might for Cloud Run when released.

Comment: Thanks, I was going to ask the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not possible in Cloud Run, as already said on the comments to your question.

You could check if there are any Feature Request for this functionality on [Buganizer](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/5447537) (Google Issue Tracker), currently there seems to be none, and if that is indeed the case, you can [create a new Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=608076&template=0) by changing the request type from Bug to Feature Request and as Google develops it on their road map, you will be informed.

Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. The general idea that one usually has is to use path mapping and map / to your client and /server to your backend. After googling for a while I found this:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains

> Base path mapping: not supported
>
> The term base path refers to the URL
>   path name that is after the domain name. For example, users is the
>   base path of example.com/users. Cloud Run only allows you to map a
>   domain to /, not to a specific base path. So any path routing has to
>   be handled by using a router inside the service's container or by
>   using Firebase Hosting.

**Option1:**

I ended up creating an "all in one" docker image with an nginx as reverse proxy and the client (some static files) and server (in my case a python application powered by uwsgi).

If you are looking for inspiration, you can check out the public repository here: https://gitlab.com/psono/psono-combo

**Opttion2:**

An alternative would be to host your client on *client.example.com*, your server on *server.example.com* and then create a third docker run instance with a reverse proxy under *example.com*.
All requestes would be "proxied" to the client and server. Your users will only interact with *example.com* so CORS won't be an issue.

**Option3:**

Configure CORS, so people accessing example.com can also connect to server.example.com